# I can't click the save button when creating a new collection in Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, collections

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwGR5.png)

I try to creat a collection in cloud firestore, but it never let me save even if I put the same information as other people who are able to creat. The photo is in the link, if it helps. I try turning off my antivirus, and switching from Chrome to Firefox, but having no luck. Can anyone help with this problem, I'll be grateful!

Comment: "never let me save" doesn't provide enough information. What exactly happens?

Comment: I am not sure, but I put the same information as other people who are able to creat, but just not working for me. The photo is in the link, if it helps.

Comment: Have you tried to name the collection in English?

Comment: yes I use english as the name of the collection, and i try to use english as my default language, but none of them let me save, the button is just grey and unclickable.

Comment: Have you tried to use another browser like Internet Explorer?

Comment: I tried edge, firefox and chrome, but have no luck.......

Comment: Give it a try and write directly to the Firebase team. When you get an answer, write here, so other future visitors can benefit.

Comment: Same problem for me too, i think it has something to do with security rules, im not sure but yeah. im trying to change the firestore rules from production to testing, ill get back to u asap and tell if it works

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same issue, when i initialized the firestore, it defaulted to  production mode. And when i was trying to create a new collection, the button to save is greyed out. So i thought it has something to do with the security rules, so i changed from production mode to testing mode. You can change it by going to CloudFirestore>Rules>Edit rules

Production mode:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
```

Testing mode:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
             request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 18, 4);
           }
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you already have the config in testing mode, replace it with the production config, update it, put back the testing config, and then refresh your webpage that should do it.